# How to implement External storage in android

Tags: android

I am new to android development and i want to implement an external storage on SD card so as to store username for particular application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store username, you just need to implement [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), also check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) article.

For example:

**Storing time:**

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = myPrefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putString("username, "pareshmayani");
        prefsEditor.commit();
```

**Retrieval Time:**

```
 SharedPreferences myPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
 String prefName = myPrefs.getString("username", null);
```

Comment: how to know that the Username is stored previously?

Comment: check whether the username is null or not.

Comment: is there any file generates after this kind of data storing?